# React project WebsocketServer.js SyntaxError on heartbeatInterval

Tags: reactjs

I created a React project that uses webpack-dev-server and my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "testproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "lint": "eslint **/*.{js,jsx} --quiet",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.58.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm run start`, I'm getting this error:

```
[webpack-cli] C:\dev\testproject\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\servers\WebsocketServer.js:10
  static heartbeatInterval = 1000;
 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (C:\dev\testproject\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
    at Module._compile (C:\dev\testproject\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:184:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (C:\dev\testproject\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Server.getServerTransport (C:\dev\testproject\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:1009:28)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! testproject@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open`
```

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out upgrading my node version (in my case, from `10.13.0` to `16.11.1`) resolved this.

I tried this based on advice found [here](https://github.com/VickScarlet/lifeRestart/issues/176) and it worked.

Comment: Although the answer gives a solution, it is not directly answering the question of what is causing the issue.

Comment: Agreed. The link includes some brief discussion re: syntax changes which could be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Your babel transpiling is not set up properly you need to add appropriates plugins in your babel config.

Basically this error means that below statement is not supported, and thats because babel is not transpiling your code to a supported ES version.

```
 static heartbeatInterval = 1000;
```

you may have to use this plugin: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Comment: Hm, I tried adding adding that plugin as you advise (via npm install) and also added the plugin to my .babelrc (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties#usage) - but so far I'm still getting the same error.